# How to center text shadow

Tags: css

Is there any way to center text shadow?

I would like to get shadow like this:

[image]

im using:

```
 text-shadow: 0.1em 1.0em 2.5em black;
```

but of course text isnt centered.

Comment: `text-shadow: 0 0 2.5em black;` - the first two parameters are for x and y axis.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below css code.

`text-shadow: 0 0 6px #000000;`

It helps to provide center text shadow.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
text-shadow: 0 0 <value suitable> <suitable color>
```

*eg.*

```
text-shadow: 0 0 2em #888
```